# Web Application Architecture?

Tags: iphone, android, web-services, architecture

I’m scoping a new software project and haven’t had much experience with software development. This is a multipart question.

1. What are some recommended books for web application architecture?
2. We are basically looking to develop several front end applications (mobile and websites) that can query a central application pool that’ll hit our backend database to retrieve the data. Is there a name for this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are some recommended books for web application architecture?

That depends on the design pattern you will use. MVC (Model-View-Controller) is a good pattern. The Model is the database, Controller is the middle between the other two (where all the business and logic is), and View is what you see in the browser.
There is no one answer as to what MVC should you use. For example you can choose MySQL as the Model, Java Servlets as the Controller and jQuery for View.

> We are basically looking to develop several front end applications (mobile and websites) that can query a central application pool that’ll hit our backend database to retrieve the data. Is there a name for this kind of architecture?

Depends on your platform, if you are on Windows then WAMP is a good place to start from, it already has Apache application server, MySQL database, and PHP.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with software development (like most things in life) is that there are so many choices and so many opinions.  I would get help from someone with experience and references.  Find someone/company that has done something similar.  You should also go to any computer store and search around for books on similar architectures (since your tags show iphone, webservices, andriod - there are tons of books out there).

After you get someone to give you advice on the architecture make sure you ask about cost, time, and seeing results frequently.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know some HTML, look into PHP. It's not a good language but it gets the job done, it's free, and it gives you a lot of flexibility in getting your idea up and running.

I don't know though, "I don't have much experience in software development." You're going to have your work cut out for you. You will need to know the basics of programming, the basics of HTTP, working with databases, and maybe even some system configuration. You might be getting in over your head.

To answer #2 though - one name you'll commonly see is LAMP - Linux/Apache/MySQL/PHP. Some people sub out some of those things for something else (for example, Python for PHP) but in essence it means a free application stack.